# grouping similar models in a Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone collection, where I am iterating through and looking up mdl.get('group'). This returns:

`[undefined, undefined, group, group, group, undefined, group, group, group, undefined, group, group]`

What I would like it to return is arrays (or collections) of those group models:

`[undefined, undefined, [group], undefined, [group], undefined, [group]`

I am trying to think of the best way to:

- iterate through the object
- return 'undefined' values without changing them
- find siblings with similar values
- collapse them into an array, within the object

Much like the _.groupBy method, but I need to retain the correct order of the models within the object.

I would love some ideas on how to approach this. So far I'm stumbling on how to tackle this one correctly.

thanks!

Comment: A clarification: aside from the general routine, similar models get grouped if they have the same, given attribute?

Comment: that sounds right, similar models are grouped by the given attribute. If siblings are separated by not having this attribute (undefined) then we move on to the next grouping of models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tinkering, came up with this solution. I extended Array.prototype so that you can easily drop it in. You can make an Underscore extension or a Collection.prototype method out of it:

```
Array.prototype.pack = function(field) {
    var result = [], target, lastItem;
    while(this.length > 0) {
        var item = this.shift();
        if(item === undefined) {
            target = result;
        } else {
            if(!lastItem || item[field] != lastItem[field]) {
                target = [];
                result.push(target);
            }
        }
        target.push(item);
        lastItem = item;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note it wasn't heavy tested, and for sure it can be refined, but should give you an idea. 
You can use it like this:

```
models.pack("name")
```

where models is a plain array like [undefined, {field:value}].

Tried to be as concise as possible. A working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/YZQ6v/

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection.groupBy() to do this. First groupBy "group" to create a hash of grouped models then use collection.map to map the siblings onto the models.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/puleos/w7drB/

```
var models = [
    {name: "Scott", group: "alpha"}, 
    {name: "Rose", group: "alpha"}, 
    {name: "Charles", group: "alpha"}, 
    {name: "Stan"}, 
    {name: "John"}, 
    {name: "Mary", group: "beta"}, 
    {name: "Dan", group: "beta"}, 
    {name: "Paul", group: "beta"}, 
    {name: "Grace"}, 
    {name: "Sarah", group: "omega"} 
];

var SourceCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});

var sourceCollection = new SourceCollection(models);
var grouped = sourceCollection.groupBy('group');

sourceCollection.map(function(model) {
  if(model.has("group")) {
      model.set({siblings: grouped[model.get("group")]});
  }
});

// sourceCollection with siblings 
console.log(sourceCollection);
```